# post to instagram and facebook using api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Let's say I have a facebook page, if any post happens on that page the same content should also get posted automatically on my instagram as well. how can I achieve that, I have been looking at facebook graph api documentation for hours now but I am very confused, any guideline on which approach should I take?

Answer (score 1):

Instagram does not offer any API to post to their platform. I am afraid there is no way.

Edit: There is an option, but it is limited to IG business accounts: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: They got https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing now, but that is limited to IG business accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Graph API:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/ and Instagram Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/
In order to post anything on Instagram, you need a creator or a Business account. Also, you need to connect Facebook and Instagram in order to post anything. That is because posting on Instagram is done indirectly through Facebook pages. See here for more info on how it can be done: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview